# Как сверстать блок с изогнутой линией?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animation

Никак не получается заверстать вот такой блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экран на 100vh. Девушка явно абсолютом, но вот как её прижать к волнистой линии, что бы она всегда была ровно? Стоит чуть изменить высоту экрана и она уезжает.
Пробовал вырезать её на фон, но это не подходит т.к. она будет не масштабироваться и на её размер отдельно я не смогу влиять.

Comment: Как сверстана сама изогнутая линия?

Comment: Ваш вопрос с картинкой и без кода стоит закрыть.

Comment: @Mully да никак. Вырезал вместе с фоном. Пока решил проблему тремя фонами), но по хорошему наверное нужно через clip-path или svg.

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из комментария TC:

> Пока решил проблему тремя фонами), но по хорошему наверное нужно через
> clip-path или svg.

Именно так и решена проблема изогнутой линии, разделяющей изображение и остальную часть HTML страницы.

Изогнутая линия рисуется в векторном редакторе и изображение обрезается с помощью `clipPath` SVG

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


.header {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;  
  padding-top:0.5em;
}
.content {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  min-height:15%;
}
.footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top:-20px;
  position:relative;
  height:7%;
}
.footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
p {
padding:1em;
font-size:18px;
color:inherit;
font-family: Arial, serif;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Header
         <svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="80%" viewBox="0 0 1254 639" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYmin meet" style="border:0px solid" >  
<defs>
 <mask id="cp"> 
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" /> 
   <path fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M 24.931997,548.48601 V 21.12007 H 1182.6439 v 450.94395 c 0,0 -61.0932,16.05611 -92.14,21.68 -44.806,8.11626 -90.1116,13.69079 -135.5,17.34399 -54.05529,4.35077 -108.37179,4.96588 -162.59999,5.42 -65.40801,0.54774 -130.80712,-1.92529 -196.20397,-3.252 -45.17038,-0.91637 -90.32076,-3.05219 -135.49999,-3.252 -47.701,-0.21096 -95.42949,0.14354 -143.08798,2.168 -41.43616,1.76015 -82.53642,5.39964 -124.11799,8.672 -52.03726,4.0952 -168.561983,27.642 -168.561983,27.642 z" />
     
 </mask>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#939393" /> 
<rect x="92" y="25" width="1070" height="618" fill="#FFDA98" stroke="#230414" stroke-width="0"/>
<image mask="url(#cp)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/khBVk.gif" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <text x="300" y="200" fill="#F0F0F0" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px">Ресторанная анимация
   <tspan x="300" y="220"> и мастер классы </tspan>
    <tspan x="300" y="240" font-size="16px"> от Ирины Мироновой </tspan>
  </text> 
     <text x="500" y="600" fill="#564933" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="18px">О компании в цифрах </text>
</svg>

</div>
     <div class="content">
     
     <p>Ресторанная анимация – это новая досуговая деятельность, предлагаемая в ресторанах, кафе и других предприятия общественного питания, которая в той или иной форме существовала также ранее, но имела иные способы выражения.
     </p>   
    </div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
  </div>

</div>          
  
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

- Вариант с анимацией линии

Анимация реализована с помощью изменения атрибута `d` path

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


.header {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-top:0.5em;
}
.content {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  min-height:15%;
}
.footer {
  background: #061D25;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top:-20px;
  position:relative;
  height:7%;
}
.footer a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #70726F;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.footer a:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #70726F;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
p {
padding:1em;
font-size:18px;
color:inherit;
font-family: Arial, serif;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Header
         <svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="100%" height="80%" viewBox="0 0 1254 639" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYmin meet" style="border:0px solid" >  
<defs>
 <mask id="cp"> 
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" /> 
   <path fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M 24.931997,548.48601 V 21.12007 H 1182.6439 v 450.94395 c 0,0 -61.0932,16.05611 -92.14,21.68 -44.806,8.11626 -90.1116,13.69079 -135.5,17.34399 -54.05529,4.35077 -108.37179,4.96588 -162.59999,5.42 -65.40801,0.54774 -130.80712,-1.92529 -196.20397,-3.252 -45.17038,-0.91637 -90.32076,-3.05219 -135.49999,-3.252 -47.701,-0.21096 -95.42949,0.14354 -143.08798,2.168 -41.43616,1.76015 -82.53642,5.39964 -124.11799,8.672 -52.03726,4.0952 -168.561983,27.642 -168.561983,27.642 z" >
     <animate
        attributeName="d"
        begin="0s"
        dur="6s"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        restart="whenNotActive"
        values="
               M 24.931997,548.48601 V 21.12007 H 1182.6439 v 450.94395 c 0,0 -61.0932,16.05611 -92.14,21.68 -44.806,8.11626 -90.1116,13.69079 -135.5,17.34399 -54.05529,4.35077 -108.37179,4.96588 -162.59999,5.42 -65.40801,0.54774 -130.80712,-1.92529 -196.20397,-3.252 -45.17038,-0.91637 -90.32076,-3.05219 -135.49999,-3.252 -47.701,-0.21096 -95.42949,0.14354 -143.08798,2.168 -41.43616,1.76015 -82.53642,5.39964 -124.11799,8.672 -52.03726,4.0952 -168.561983,27.642 -168.561983,27.642 z;
               M 24.931997,548.48601 V 21.12007 H 1182.6439 v 450.94395 c 0,0 -29.6572,26.89611 -60.704,32.52 -44.806,8.11626 -117.2116,21.27879 -162.6,24.93199 -54.05529,4.35077 -112.70779,-13.46212 -166.93599,-13.008 -65.40801,0.54774 -119.96712,14.33471 -185.36397,13.008 -45.17038,-0.91637 -101.16076,-19.31219 -146.33999,-19.512 -47.701,-0.21096 -148.54549,21.82354 -196.20398,23.848 -41.43616,1.76015 -154.08041,-29.28836 -195.66198,-26.016 -52.03726,4.0952 -43.901993,40.65 -43.901993,40.65 z;
               M 24.931997,548.48601 V 21.12007 H 1182.6439 v 450.94395 c 0,0 -61.0932,16.05611 -92.14,21.68 -44.806,8.11626 -90.1116,13.69079 -135.5,17.34399 -54.05529,4.35077 -108.37179,4.96588 -162.59999,5.42 -65.40801,0.54774 -130.80712,-1.92529 -196.20397,-3.252 -45.17038,-0.91637 -90.32076,-3.05219 -135.49999,-3.252 -47.701,-0.21096 -95.42949,0.14354 -143.08798,2.168 -41.43616,1.76015 -82.53642,5.39964 -124.11799,8.672 -52.03726,4.0952 -168.561983,27.642 -168.561983,27.642 z" 
               />
   </path>
 </mask>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#939393" /> 
<rect x="92" y="25" width="1070" height="618" fill="#FFDA98" stroke="#230414" stroke-width="0"/>
<image mask="url(#cp)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/khBVk.gif" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <text x="300" y="200" fill="#F0F0F0" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px">Ресторанная анимация
   <tspan x="300" y="220"> и мастер классы </tspan>
    <tspan x="300" y="240" font-size="16px"> от Ирины Мироновой </tspan>
  </text> 
     <text x="500" y="600" fill="#564933" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="18px">О компании в цифрах </text>
</svg>

</div>
     <div class="content">
     
     <p>Ресторанная анимация – это новая досуговая деятельность, предлагаемая в ресторанах, кафе и других предприятия общественного питания, которая в той или иной форме существовала также ранее, но имела иные способы выражения.
     </p>   
    </div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
  </div>

</div>          
  
  </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```